# How to register a userId to Bluemix Push Notifications services?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

the REST API documentation for Bluemix Push Notification services states that the possible push notification targets are deviceIds, platforms, tagNames and userIds.

I don't understand how you register a userId for a device ? I don't see any REST service that seem to take a userId in its inputs...

Thanks for your help,

Sebastien

Comment: Can you please clarify specifically which Push Notification service you are using? There's "IBM Push Notifications" (sometimes imfPush) and there is "Push". Sorry for the confusing nomenclature, if your Push service icon is grey then it is "Push".

Comment: I'm talking about IBM Push Notifications (the last version of the service)

Comment: I know the old Push had consumerIds that were set client-side when registering, investigating how that was migrated to the new stuff because I'm not seeing it in the current api. What piece of documentation specifically are you looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a deviceId that you can set from the REST API when using the [POST devices call](https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/#!/devices/post_apps_applicationId_devices) to register a device.

In the `DeviceRegResponseModel` is `userId (string, optional): The user identifier for the the device registration`

So essentially to set a userId you'll just want to add that to the json you send when registering a device through the REST API. So just modifying the example the REST API gives for the body:

```
{
  "deviceId": "TestDeviceId",
  "platform": "A",
  "token": "************",
  "userId": "John"
}
```

And then you can use the [POST messages call](https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/#!/messages/post_apps_applicationId_messages) with `"userId": "John"` in your `target` body to send that message to all devices registered with the userId "John".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps ! I guess that the documentation of the body schema for the POST and PUT methods should be updated accordingly.

Comment: Yep, I've issued a request to our documentation team to have everything updated. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.