# Bluemix Push Notification service iOS SDK

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

While using the latest Bluemix Push Notification service's iOS SDK, is there a way to specify a userId during device registration? The current documentation only addresses tag based notification subscriptions and basic notification subscriptions, but I'm looking for a mechanism to specify the userId via the Push iOS SDK.
Note - I've read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022608/how-to-register-a-userid-to-bluemix-push-notifications-services) posted previously but it addresses registration via REST calls

Answer (score 0):

At this time the Bluemix Push Notification SDKs do not support userIds due to a security loophole that was encountered in the original implementation. It is my understanding that adding secure userIds is a goal for the team and I am currently trying to get in touch with them to see if there's anything I can relay with regards to an ETA.

At this time the REST call work-around is the only one I know of.

Answer (score 0):

@sunil32 The mechanism to specify the userId via the Push iOS SDK is available in the latest SDK, you can give a try by updating the pod or carthage.

Comment: {
  "deviceId": "TestDeviceId",
  "platform": "A",
  "token": "************",
  "userId": "John"
}