# Bluemix Mobile Push Notification Service, how to register by consumerId

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

When send push notification messages, consumerIds can be specified as target. But when register the device, I don't see where to supply the consumerId in the SDK doc.

[Register iOS Devices](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/enablepush_ios.html#t_push_register_ios)

[Register Android Devices](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/enablepush_android.html#t_push_register_android)

Can you let me know how to register with the consumerId?

Thanks,

Jen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to register a consumerId / userId through the Android and iOS SDKs. This is a feature that existed prior but was removed due to security issues when  dealing with the public facing REST APIs. It is my understanding that work is being done to reintroduce the functionality but I know nothing more than that.

That said it is possible to recreate the functionality through the REST API (https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/#!/devices/put_apps_applicationId_devices_deviceId)

In short what you would need to do it register the device normally through iOS or Android, then execute the REST GET devices/{deviceId} using the deviceId obtained at the time of registration. From there you could copy off the data, insert your desired consumerId and then execute PUT devices/{deviceId} using that data to update the device registration with the new consumerId.

The answer I posted here goes over that in a little more detail
[How to register a userId to Bluemix Push Notifications services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022608/how-to-register-a-userid-to-bluemix-push-notifications-services/34069984#34069984)

Again unfortunately it's pretty convuluted to execute at this point while we wait on the native SDKs to reacquire the functionality. In some cases it may be wiser to just create your own mapping of deviceIds to consumerIds and use deviceIds as your push parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check this documentation of the rest API for IBM Push Notification?
https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/mbaas-api/?cm_mc_uid=70457747682413998998889&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1456154344#!/push/sendMessage_post_21

There's optional parameters for consummerIds and deviceIds.

There's also this more complex API documentation of IBMPushService:
https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/mbaas-api/docs/JavaScript/IBMPushService.html?cm_mc_uid=70457747682413998998889&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1456154344

Comment: Unfortunately both of these doc links are for the deprecated IBM Push service rather than the current "IBM Push Notifications" service. If "mbaas" is in the url you can safely assume the document is for the deprecated services. The REST API for IBM Push Notifications is https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/ and the API documentation is sadly out of date which would lead me to look at the GitHub repo for the service: https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-android-push/tree/development/lib/src/main/java/com/ibm/mobilefirstplatform/clientsdk/android/push/api